# What is the best way to implement algebraic structures and their elements?

Tags: rust

There are a lot of crates online that focus on implementing algebraic structures like groups, rings, and fields. However it seems like these crates are focused on the structures themselves (re: Alga) or on their elements (maybe? re: maths_traits).

I'm looking for a framework that balances both algebraic structures and their elements. For example, I want to be able to both instantiate a ring which I can quotient with an ideal to produce a new algebraic structure, but I also want to be able to work with elements of this ring.

I've given this quite a few attempts but have never found anything that feels like a nice solution. Are there any libraries that do this, or does anyone have ideas as to how to make this work?

To be clear, here are some of the issues I have: say I define a trait for rings. Then elements of this ring should take this ring as a generic. But then the ring itself doesn't know anything about it's elements. As an example:

```
pub trait Ring {}
pub trait RingElem<T: Ring> {}

pub struct IntegerRing {}
impl Ring for IntegerRing {}

pub struct Integer {}
impl RingElem<IntegerRing> for Integer {}

// now IntegerRing doesn't know about Integer, so how can I do something like IntegerRing::zero()?
```

I know my concerns are a bit vague but I'm hoping someone can point me to a solution that someone else has used to work around these issues.

Comment: Perhaps you could use an associated type (https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) on the `Ring` trait to represent elements? You could bound it like, `type Element: RingElem<Self>;` if you want the two-trait structure.

Comment: @alphamodder that seems like it could work, I'll have to give it more thought but consider making it an answer